# align 4 divs in parallel where one of the divs is empty

Tags: css, html, css-float

I'm a newbie with html so please be patient.

I'm trying to align 4 divs in parallel where the first,third and fourth div are static,the second div is empty and i need it to occupy the remain place e.g "width:auto".
I don't want to use table to solve the problem.
Is there a way to solve it using divs?

HTML:

```
   <div class="container">
        <div class="content" >
            first
        </div>
        <div class="empty">

        </div>
        <div class="content">
         third
        </div>
        <div class="content">
         fourth
        </div>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
   .container{
        strong textwidth:1020px;
        height:40px;
    }

    .content{
        position:relative;
        background-color:#2cc2e7;
        height:40px;
        width:142px;
        float:right;
        margin-right:5px;
    }

    .empty{
        background-color:#f1d486;
        height:40px;
        width:auto;
        margin-right:5px;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to change the order of the elements:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="first content">first</div>
  <div class="content">third</div>
  <div class="content">fourth</div>
  <div class="empty"></div>
</div>
```

And then just float the first one to the left, other two to the right, and the `.empty` one, don't float it but set an overflow to auto —or hidden.

```
.content {
  float: right;
  width: 142px;
}

.first {
  float: left;
}

.empty {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GTbnz/

Answer (score 0):

If you are prepared to add &nbsp; below the empty div then you could use the following:

```
<div class="empty">
    &nbsp;
</div>
```

with a style sheet of:

```
.container {
    width:1020px;
    height:40px;
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.container div {
    height:40px;
    display:table-cell;
}
.content {
    background-color:#2cc2e7;
    width:142px;
    max-width:142px;
}
.empty {
    background-color:#f1d486;
}
```

This was whichever of the 4 div's has a class 'empty' will auto-expand to fill the available space and the other div sizes will all be 142 px.